# Encrypting files with different public keys

Tags: windows, gpg, pgp

How can I encrypt three different files, each with its own public key?

For instance, there are three companies `(X, Y and Z)`. Each company sends me its own public key.

I want to send a file to each company and encrypt it using the correct matching key.

1- encrypt `file1.txt` by `x.pub` and send it to company `X`

2- encrypt `file2.txt` by `y.pub` and send it to company `Y`

3- encrypt `file3.txt` by `z.pub` and send it to company `Z`

How can I do the above in a Windows batch file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you first have to import the keys in your keyring. After that it's quite easy to automate.

I believe that this should work:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring x.gpg --import x.pub
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring x.gpg --encrypt file1.txt

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring y.gpg --import y.pub
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring y.gpg --encrypt file2.txt

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring z.gpg --import z.pub
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring z.gpg --encrypt file3.txt
```

Do note that the import step is only required the first time (assuming that you don't delete the `x.gpg` files.

Comment: Looks right to me, three files, three keys. Not a script as such, but does the job!

Comment: when i execute the following command the following error appear :- `C:\>"C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe" -r --no-default-keyring --keyring bank_1.gpg --encrypt D:\SSC\keys\port.txt
gpg: --no-default-keyring: skipped: public key not found
gpg: D:\SSC\keys\port.txt: encryption failed: public key not found`

Comment: @Mohammad AL-Rawabdeh: apparently `gpg` is having problems locating your public key in the keyring. Are you sure the path is correct? Did the `--import` step run without errors?

Comment: yes `--import` run without any error